# UISearchController and NavigationBar back

Tags: ios, swift

I'm addapting this code in my project https://github.com/stuartbreckenridge/UISearchControllerWithSwift

After Navigation Controller and before Countries Scene (ViewController) I have put one more View Controller, so now in Countries View controller I have back button. After inputing something in search bar when I press Back, search bar still is visible.

I've tried hide it doing this (countrySearchController is UISearchController):

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.countrySearchController.active = false
}
```

But it hides UISearchController with delay, so it's stil visible for half a second.

Input something:
[image]

And then press back:
[image]

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Correct way probably is to set `self.definesPresentationContext` in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

That caused some glitches when `UISearchController` became active, so I just removed the `searchBar` from `Superview`.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    searchController.searchBar.removeFromSuperview()
    searchController.active = false;
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
}
```